# Is it correct to use PUT with multipart content?

Tags: rest, http, spring, http-request

We are using Spring and want to implement a REST with a "override file" call so we think using PUT verb with a multipart body only to find that Spring don't accept it.

My question is it can't be done in Spring because it isn't the REST way to have a multipart body with PUT?

Note: I know there are ways to skip this restriction in Spring or that I can use POST but I want to stick to REST style if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you GET the same resource at the same URI, what do you expect to get back? Do you expect to get the same multipart content that you sent, i.e. the data and the file, or just one of them?

If it's the latter, then it's not a RESTful use of PUT, since one URI no longer refers to one resource. You would be better off considering using POST, or splitting the multipart content into two separate resources.

Comment: `POST` and `PUT` have entirely different meanings -- one creates, the other idempotently inserts. What would you suggest using instead of `PUT` for an idempotent insert? Without that, this answer is just "`PUT` with multipart is bad, don't use it", which is... useless.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what the GET in the api is doing but I think it is restful to have a multipart PUT.  The type of the payload doesn't change semantics of what a PUT is in REST.

For example if I had an Amazon S3 like REST api it would be restful to update the file content if a multipart PUT was made on a resource.

Comment: What is S3? ....

Comment: Good question, just edited it for clarity on S3.

Comment: Well, and now, what is an Amazon S3? Why it will be RESTful in this case?

Comment: It is a cloud storage service which is apparently less known than I thought..  The payload of the PUT would be the exact content of the subsequent GET for that resource.

Comment: Ohh I see now. So more or less you are saying the same as @Tim, aren't you?